# Not Reaching "Failed Authorisation" Page

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am sorry to ask such a basic question but it is driving me nuts.
I have an asp net core 2 application that uses the standard authorisation process (via EF and using a MySQL database). Everything works fine - the whole login process and subsequent routing - until I test with a user that does not have sufficient privileges for a particular controller. I have the following in ConfigureServices:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie (options => {
    options.LoginPath = new PathString ("/Account/LogIn");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString ("/Account/AccessDenied");
});
```

The controller (class AccountController) is as follows:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AccessDenied (string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.PageHeading = "Authorisation Problem";
    return View ();
}
```

Login works OK but, when the protected controller is called, the browser shows that it is looking for http://localhost:55800/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2F but does not reach the controller and returns 404.

I have tried numerous combinations of routing - both attribute and global, also 'returnUrl' capitalised and not. The problem seems to be that the routing system expects the first parameter in a GET to be preceded by a '/', with any subsequent parameters following the '?'. However, this URL is automatically generated.

Am I missing something fundamental? I shall be grateful for any help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dumbo!

I just found the route `{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{*parms}` which did the job.